# How to detect the path of selected nodes to the last one in an angular tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have to select the first or second fortnight of a given month and year but I am only able to capture the last selected node, so I know which fortnight has been selected but not which month or which year.

I don't know how to get the full path to the last selected node

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution

[image]

I have based it on the fact that the children of the year are always 12 months and the children of the month 2 fortnights

Thanks